# Sql Server Management Studio - Programmatically Creating Scripts based on DAL; Why use SET ANSI_NULLS ON before each table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, scripting, ansi-sql

I'm looking to generate the SQL scripts for table creation programmatically based on class definitions in my DAL similar to SQL Server Management Studio.

So, when I right click on a table in MS SMS, and tell it to script table as > Create to > new query window, it generates some very understandable code.  However, I'm not sure why they generate a few of the following lines:

- SET ANSI_NULLS ON
- SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
- SET ANSI_PADDING ON

  - {TABLE DEF GOES HERE}
- SET ANSI_PADDING OFF

I have looked these statements in the [product documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx), and understand what they are for, but am not sure why they are generated around each table declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These settings are stored with the table or code definition.
If you set these *in* a stored proc, then they are ignored at runtime.

So, if you script the table, you need to script the settings too. Especially if you have computed columns etc too.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering specifically what these statements did during table creation.  I assumed it was a good idea to also generate them, but wanted a bit more on why I need them. Thanks for your input.